# Changing the classpath order in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Some time back, I had written a library in java-play.

I wanted to re-use this library, so I added in my sbt dependencies.

But the problem is, I had to modify a couple of files and I don't have source files (only jar). 
So I have created classes with same class name and package name and added it to my new project.

But when I run my project, it still picks up my old file.

*If it was Java world, I would have modified my classpath file and everything would have been fine, but this is play framework.*

When I looked more into this issue, I landed at [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.1/ide).

> A play application classpath is built as follows (in this order):
>
> The /conf directory for the application The
>   $PLAY_PATH/framework/play.jar All jar files found in your application
>   /lib directory All jar files found in the $PLAY_PATH/framework/lib
>   directory

Is there a way to change the classpath, so that it picks my file first and then the libraries?

Comment: for some reason, you mention outdated documentation for Play 1. Why you couldn't modified classpath for Play as well? It's still a JVM world

Comment: I know it is an outdated version. But I couldn't find the newer version document for the same. so I have shared the link which was available.

Setting classpath in play, is that is what this question is all about...